# bash script doesn't work on different computers

Tags: bash, macos

I have some scripts I wrote on one computer, but the exact same thing pasted into another computer wont' compile. Why not?

The script is:

```
alias push=gitPush

gitPush() {
    branch_name=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
    NUM=$(echo $branch_name | grep -o '\([0-9]\+\)')

    # push to branch
    read -p 'Do you have any files to add? ' yn

    case $yn in
       [Yy]* ) echo 'Adding...'; git add .;git commit -a -m 'ITEM-'$NUM':';git commit --amend;...;;
       * ) echo 'Acceptable input: y/n/q';;
    esac
}
```

On the first line in the `case`, I'm getting a syntax error. But this exact script works on one computer.

EDIT:

Here is another script that fails.

```
cleanBranches() {
   echo 'Cleaning branches...'
   # the line below fails with:
   # syntax error near unexpected token `'refs/heads/develop''
   IGNORE_BRANCHES=('refs/heads/develop' 'refs/heads/master')
}
```

Comment: Add a definitive shebang instead of letting existing user shell determine?  What is different about the one machine where it doesn't run?  What error(s) do you get, or how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @ivanivan It won't even build (is that what you call it), when I run `source ~/.bash_profile` to activate it. And yes, I don't need to let users type something in shell, but I have other scripts that complain on the lines inside `case` statements too.

Comment: Are you sure your shell is `bash`? On many Linux systems the default interactive shell is `dash`.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Barmar, no I'm not sure actually. How do I tell? Both computers are macs so I assumed they were the same. The error message is: `.bash_profile: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token )'`

Comment: What does `echo $0` say?

Comment: Line 18 is the line that begins with `[Yy]*`?

Comment: @Barmar `dash` as an interactive shell? What systems are those?

Comment: @melpomene I was confused, what I'd read is that `/bin/sh` is a link to `dash`. The same misunderstanding as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292596/why-is-the-default-shell-on-my-ubuntu-14-04-bash

Comment: `dash` wouldn't source `.bash_profile`.
@JB1, What velsion of bash is giving this? `bash --version` perhaps the system is running a really old version

Comment: Have you aliased `case` on the computer where it fails? BTW, the first `grep` and `sed` commands have invalid regular expressions.

Comment: Instead of using `grep` and `sed` to pull just the current branch from `git`. It's a lot easier to use this command: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`. Also `--amend` is misspelled.

Comment: @Bamar: yes, line 18 is the `[Yy]* )` line.

Comment: @DanN: Bash version is: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)`. I'm using Mac High Sierra. I updated the code to `--amend` (it was spelled correctly in my bash_profile, I just typed it wrong here.)

Comment: @Barmar Where did you want me to put `echo $0`? When I did: `[Yn]* ) echo $0;;` it outputs the same error for `unexpected token` on the same line.

Comment: I added one more example for an unrelated script that fails, in case it shines any light on the issue.

Comment: I wanted you to just type it at the terminal, to find out what your interactive shell is.

Comment: @Barmar directly from terminal, `echo $0` outputs `-bash`